# How to bind values when using FluentSelect

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0, fluent-ui, fast-blazor

I'm struggling binding values when using a FluentSelect. Can someone see what is wrong with the following?

```
<EditForm Model="..." OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
...
<FluentSelect @bind-Value=@intValue TOption="int">
    <FluentOption Value=1>
        Option 1
    </FluentOption>
    <FluentOption Value=2>
        Option 2
    </FluentOption>
</FluentSelect>
```

-- Code behind --

```
int intValue;

protected async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{
    var i = intValue;
}
```

-- Edit --

[How to two-way-bind a value in FluentListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73497934/how-to-two-way-bind-a-value-in-fluentlistbox) doesn't help me. It refers to the FluentListBox control, which apparently doesn't work with Forms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to two-way-bind a value in FluentListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73497934/how-to-two-way-bind-a-value-in-fluentlistbox)

Comment: Try to use `@key` with you options !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
<FluentSelect @bind-Value=@intValue TOption="int">

int intValue;
```

but the Value property is always a `string`, not a `TOption`.

The basic fix:

```cs
string intValue;

protected async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{
    var i = int.Parse(intValue);
}
```